# Thumbnail изображения из sd

Tags: android, изображения, bitmap

Здравствуйте. 
Знаю путь к изображению, которое лежит на sd карте. Как можно получить ее превью?

Answer (score 1):

```
// получение файла
File file = new File("путь");
// получение пути
String imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
//собственно, сама картинка
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
```

А дальше уже можете уменьшать её.

Например так можно скейлить, чтобы получить превьюшку:

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // коэффициент скейла ищем, степенью двойки должен быть
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Каждый раз декодировать изображение накладно.  У меня список изображении и при прокрутке притормаживаются.

Comment: @Sergey Kostin можно декодировать один раз и грузить в хэшмеп, я обычно LinkedHashMap использую.
Так что можно сохранять превьюшку на диск, чтобы в дальнейшем заново не скалировать каждый раз.